# Trying to send a HTML document from ASP.NET MVC to JavaScript and show with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send a html document from ASP.NET MVC to JavaScript, and then populate a Kendo windo in an iFrame with the new data.

Here's what works. I can make the pop up window's content complete replaced with a simple hardcoded html page after a response comes back from the controller:

```
  function formSubmit() {
      $.post($('form').attr("action"), $("form").serialize(), function(data){
                    document.write("<html><head></head><body>this is a test</body></html>");
                }
            }
        })
  }
```

If I return some simple HTML from the controller, I can see that html in an alert box. However, it doesn't work if I put it in the document.write call. For example, here's the JavaScript:

```
  function formSubmit() {
      $.post($('form').attr("action"), $("form").serialize(), function(data){
                    alert(data); // I see exactly what the controller passed back
                    document.write(data); // The pop-up page becomes blank, as if the data passed to this function is invalid.
                }
            }
        })
  }
```

In my controller, I have

```
    public ActionResult Create(VMReportObservation viewModel)
    {
        return Json("<html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>");
    }
```

On the JavaScript side, is there some sort of conversion to a string that I need to do to make the document.write() call work? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: You should be returning a partial view (`return PartialView("...");`), not json. And in the ajax, its `$.post(..., function(data) { $(someElement).html(data); });`

Comment: Is `data` at complete callback of `$.post()` a `json` object ? Can include response from controller at Question ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - what if this isn't a partial view, but I want to replace the entire page? Basically, I want to do a `$('form').submit();` but I want to look at what's returned before deciding whether to update the entire screen.

Comment: @StephenMuecke should be credited with the most correct answer. Doing a `Document.write(data)` wiped out nearly all of the Kendo controls I was using within the Kendo window. I ended up having to make a div that encompassed the view and then passed back a partial view and did the replacement as suggested.

Comment: Sort of. $(someElement).html(data) is what saves you from document.write fallout. So you could still use Content with $().html(). Although a PartialView (or, if you really are rendering an <html> block, a full View) is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning JSON. Instead,

```
return Content("<html>...</html>");
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. In JavaScript, it returns what seems to be an empty string.

Comment: My mistake. This does work. I had accidentally wiped out data in a previous part of my code, which is why I wasn't seeing anything.

Comment: Cool. Do you need anything else before marking as answered?